# Lançar Exception com erro #1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: php, mysql, exceção

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação onde o usuário digita algumas informações, duas delas são CodigoMotorista e CodigoVeiculo.

Esse é um trecho do meu código:

```
try {
        $database->query($sql);

        $_SESSION['message'] = 'Registro cadastrado com sucesso.';
        $_SESSION['type'] = 'success';
    } catch (Exception $e) {

        $_SESSION['message'] = 'Não foi possivel realizar a operação.';
        $_SESSION['type'] = 'danger';
    }
```

Estou conseguindo fazer os cadastros normais, o problema é que quando o usuário informa um **CodigoMotorista** ou **CodigoVeiculo** que não existe o sistema não dá uma *Exception* (Deveria dar uma *Exception* porque esses dados são Chaves Estrangeiras) o sistema não faz a inserção mesmo, o que preciso é adaptar esse código para dar uma Exceção com o erro ou mudar o parametro da condição, para informar o usuário que o cadastro deu erro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ele não da erro porque o `MySqli` não retorna um `Exception` da mesma maneira que o php.

Para capturar um erro do `Mysqli`, você pode criar uma função e chama-la caso a query dê erro.

```
    $database->query($sql) or die(erro());//Utilizei erro() como um exemplo de função.

    $_SESSION['message'] = 'Registro cadastrado com sucesso.';
    $_SESSION['type'] = 'success';
```

Ou fazer um `if`, já que o query irá retornar `true` caso o query tenha dado certo e `false` caso tenha dado erro: (Recomendo mais esta opção)

```
if($database->query($sql))
{
    $_SESSION['message'] = 'Registro cadastrado com sucesso.';
    $_SESSION['type'] = 'success';
}
else 
{
    $_SESSION['message'] = 'Não foi possivel realizar a operação.';
    $_SESSION['type'] = 'danger';
}
```

Comment: Usei seu 2 exemplo, muito obrigado pelo conhecimento passado pra mim.

Answer (score 0):

Oi, por que você não verifica primeiro se os campos existem com um select na tabelas corretas se não existir reencaminha para o seu erro. if row count == 0  por que se existir ou trazer um objeto é tudo o que precisa para fazer ir para o proximo conjunto de dados .
voce pode fazer uma sub funcao que faz essa busca e retorna verdadeiro ou falso.